# Converting Print page Graphics to Bitmap C#

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap

I have an application where the user can print a document of selected items in the form of an invoice. Everything works well however on the `PrintPage` event of the PrintDocument I want to capture the document or he graphics, turn it into a bitmap so I can save to it a `.bmp` for later use / viewing. (Note: There are multiple pages in this document) I have it set up like this:

```
PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(doc_PrintPage);
doc.Print();
```

Then on the `PrintPage` event:

```
private void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    // Use ev.Graphics to create the document
    // I create the document here

    // After I have drawn all the graphics I want to get it and turn it into a bitmap and save it.
}
```

I have cut out all the `ev.Graphics` code just because it is a lot of lines. Is there a way to turn the Graphics into a Bitmap without changing any of the code that draws graphics onto the `PrintDocument`? Or do something similar to that, maybe copying the document and converting it into a bitmap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should actually draw the page into the bitmap, and then use ev.Graphics to draw that bitmap on the page.

```
private void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap((int)graphics.ClipBounds.Width,
                            (int)graphics.ClipBounds.Height);

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        // Draw all the graphics using into g (into the bitmap)
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }

    // And maybe some control drawing if you want...?
    this.label1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, this.label1.Bounds);

    ev.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this soon and if it works I will report back.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Yorye Nathan's answer on Jun 3'12 at 7:33 is correct and it was the starting point that helped me.  However, I was not able to get it to work as-is, so I made some corrections to make it work in my application.  The correction is to get the Printer's page size from the PrintPgeEventArgs.Graphics Device Context, and include the PrintPage Graphics as a third parameter in the new Bitmap(...) construction.

```
private void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ppea)
{
  // Retrieve the physical bitmap boundaries from the PrintPage Graphics Device Context
  IntPtr hdc = ppea.Graphics.GetHdc();
  Int32 PhysicalWidth = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, (Int32)PHYSICALWIDTH);
  Int32 PhysicalHeight = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, (Int32)PHYSICALHEIGHT);
  ppea.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);

  // Create a bitmap with PrintPage Graphic's size and resolution
  Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(PhysicalWidth, PhysicalHeight, ppea.Graphics);
  // Get the new work Graphics to use to draw the bitmap
  Graphics myGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);

  // Draw everything on myGraphics to build the bitmap

  // Transfer the bitmap to the PrintPage Graphics
  ppea.Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, 0, 0);

  // Cleanup 
  myBitmap.Dispose();
}

////////
// Win32 API GetDeviceCaps() function needed to get the DC Physical Width and Height

const int PHYSICALWIDTH = 110;  // Physical Width in device units           
const int PHYSICALHEIGHT = 111; // Physical Height in device units          

// This function returns the device capability value specified
// by the requested index value.
[DllImport("GDI32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern Int32 GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, Int32 nIndex);
```

Thank you again Yorye Nathan for providing the original answer.
//AJ